# Getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') when trying to send image to S3 bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I am using react and trying to send an image to my S3 bucket.
Here is my code

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

function AddPlayer() {
  const [selectFile, setSelectFile] = useState(null);
  const [imageName, setImageName] = useState(null);


  const handleUpload = async () => {
    const client = new S3Client({
      region: "us-east-2",
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: "MyAccessKey",
        secretAccessKey: "MySecretKey",
      },
    });

    const params = {
      Bucket: "my-test-demo-images",
      Key: imageName,
      Body: selectFile 
    };

    const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
    const data = await client.send(command);
    console.log(data);

}

  const change = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.files[0]);
    setImageName(e.target.files[0].name);
    setSelectFile(e.target.files[0]);
    handleUpload();
  };
```

When a user changes an images in an input file tag change is called. I replaced the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey. Not sure why I am getting `Cannot read properties of null`

Here is the image of the error and file

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `selectFile` within the `PutObjectCommand` call?

Comment: @RobinThomas selectFile's value is right above the error in the image. File {name: "Bulldog.png"}

Comment: Just to clarify, are you exposing your AWS credentials in the frontend?

Comment: @RobinThomas they will be in an env file when I push them to Github, but as of now yes.

Comment: You have to pass a buffer/stream to `Key` parameter in `Body` (and not a `File` object) to be able to upload. Else, you can generate a temporary url in server, and upload to that from your browser (this way, no need to expose the credentials).